# Prevent email notification while adding a commenter in google appscript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api

I am adding commenter using google appscript using `addCommenter` function. But it sends invitation to the user. Is there any way to disable this email notification??

Here is my code

```
function shareGroup(usersToShare, sheetId) {
    var newFile =DriveApp.getFileById(sheetId);
    for (var i = 0; i <= usersToShare.length - 1; i++) { 
          newFile.addCommenter(usersToShare[i]);               
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible using the default DriveApp Service. However, you can use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to workaround around this issue (which you should [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) in the Script Editor by selecting Resources > Advanced Google services... and then enabled it in the Google Developers Console.)

The code used should be:

```
 Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {
     'role': 'reader',
     'type': 'user',
     'value': 'jane.doe@example.com',
     'additionalRoles': ['commenter']
   },
   'fileId',
   {
     'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
   });
```

Comment: "commenter" did not work. Replaced it with ["commenter"]. Working now. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, [additionalRoles](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) expects a list. I edited my code for future references.