# Inserting comment using Drive API 2.0, but dont send mail to the owner of file?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am using [Drive comment API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/insert)  to insert a comment in spreadsheet. But it sends mail to the owner of sheet. I am doing this explicitly inside my app. So owner gets two mails regarding this comment(one from google and one from my app). I have done the same thing in [google appscript while adding a commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611334/prevent-email-notification-while-adding-a-commenter-in-google-appscript). I want to know if there is any i can do it in ajax call or using [gapi](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/)

Here is my code :

```
   $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + fileId + '/comments',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(body),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
```

Comment: Where do you plan to insert the comments, is it in the comment section or attach it to/inside the spreadsheet cell?

Comment: @noogui I am inserting the comments in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

I used the link you gave, [Comments: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/insert) guide in Drive v2. I was able to insert a comment in my spreadsheet using the [Try it!](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/insert) box.
[image]
Just fill in your spreadsheetId in filedId. Choose one or all of the optional fields, and so on. When i executed the call, the comment was posted on my spreadsheet.

[image]

I did not receive any email, whatsoever.